# Extract address cell in table

Tags: excel, vba, range, listobject

I would like to have the range (address) of the cell where is my table like :

```
Column = Range(table_NB.DataBodyRange(1, 1))
```

Do you have the correct code for this ?

Comment: ok thanks, but it's not only a cell it's a table (listobject)  I would like to have the adress of the first cell of the table (row 1 col 1)

Comment: Column = ActiveCell.Column                
    row = ActiveCell.row - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the address of the first cell in a table:

```
MsgBox ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Address
```